# Expressing vectors in different bases

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, notation, linear-transformations

I am trying to wrap my head around the concept of expressing vectors in different bases, and how to 'translate' between them. 
Consider the two bases given by:
$$B={e_1,e_2,e_3},\quad B^{\prime}=\left\{\left[\begin{array}{l}
1 \\0 \\0\end{array}\right],\left[\begin{array}{l}1 \\1 \\0
\end{array}\right],\left[\begin{array}{l}
1 \\1 \\1\end{array}\right]\right\}$$
If I understood correctly, the columns of $B'$ also determine the change of basis matrix:
$$P=\left[\begin{array}{lll}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]$$
So that the basis vectors in $B$ can now be expressed in terms of the basis vectors in $B'$ (sorry for a bit sloppy notation):
$$b_{j}=\sum_{i} p_{i j} b_{i}^{\prime}, \qquad \{b_{j}\} = B, \quad \{b_{i}^{\prime}\} = B^{\prime}$$
Which in matrix notation becomes:
$$b=Pb'$$
For example, if we have a vector,$v'$, that in basis $B'$ has coordinates $(1,4,2)$, then in $B$ the same vector will have coordinates:
$$v=P v^{\prime}=\left[\begin{array}{lll}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{l}
1 \\
2 \\
4
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{l}
7 \\
6 \\
4
\end{array}\right]$$
Is there anything that I misunderstood or does this look correct?

Comment: You need to pay attention to the order: is it $(1, 4, 2)$ or is it $(1, 2, 4)$?

Comment: I will just add that because of this phenomenon vectors are said to be contravariant.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix $P$ is the matrix that changes $B'$-coordinates into $B$-coordinates. Note that $P$ arises as the matrix representantion of the identity transformation $Id:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ with respect to the bases $B'$ and $B$, respectively. This is really easy to see, since the elements of $B'$ are already written in $B$-coordinates.

So, to obtain the expression in $B$-coordinates of any vector $v = a_1b'_1 + a_2b'_2 + a_3b'_3$ written in $B'$-coordinates you use multiplication by $P$

$$[v]_B = P \begin{bmatrix}
a_1\\
a_2\\
a_3
\end{bmatrix}$$
The coordinates of $[v]_B$ give you the coefficients of $v$ in $B$-coordinates. Conversely, if you wanted to obtain $B'$-coordinates from $B$-coordinates you would have to carry out the same procedure using $P^{-1}$ instead.